# how can i set circular image view on toolbar left side, when we slide a tab the Textview changes?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-toolbar, android-tablayout

How can I set Circular image view and when we slide a tab  Textview changes?

[image]

Comment: What you want exactly?

Comment: How can I set circular imageview on left side of the toolbar and when I'm sliding a tab the textview changes. For example Twitter app the circular imageview on left side of the toolbar and when I'm sliding tab the textview changes

Answer (score 0):

you can use custom layout instead of toolbar layout

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"      
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">
        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/toolBarPicture"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_toolbaruserprogile"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

use this library

```
 compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

For circular imageview use this library- https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

And for toolbar, delete the default toolbar and create a custom one.

Answer (score 0):

use this library `compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'`

Create a custom toolbar and include it in your layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar_with_logo"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/toolBarPicture"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
    android:textAlignment="center" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/app_name"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```